# UTF8 encoded URL parameters changed by ASP.NET WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, encoding, asp.net-web-api2

I have built a very simple controller with ASP.NET WebAPI without any customization. The code is as below

```cs
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("encoding/{x}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetEncoding(string x)
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Now from the client, I need to pass a Unicode character � with URL `http://localhost:19477/encoding/�` which is encoded to `http://localhost:19477/encoding/%EF%BF%BD`. However during debugging I found the `AbsoluteUri` from `Request` object is changed to `"http://localhost:19477/encoding/%C3%AF%C2%BF%C2%BD"` which changes my original path. 
[image]

This makes the received string totally wrong from original request.

Comment: Have you tried to change your API to post instead? query strings gets encoded if it contains special characters

Comment: Do you really need unicode or a windows encoding method like Windows 1252?  ASCII characters 0x00 to 0x7F are the same for all encoding methods.The characters 0x80 to 0xFF are different for each encoding methods and maps a two byte unicode character to a one byte character to reduce so you are using only one byte instead of two bytes.The question mark usually occurs when you are using the wrong encoding method.The header of an html message will indicate the encoding method and your code looks like will take the encoding specified in the http request.You are missing the encoding in the request.